# I ran some code in Azure notebooks, the code was exactly the same but different outputs

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
data = [
 [847502, "APPLES 1LB", 1.99, 50], 
 [847283, "OLIVE OIL", 10.99, 100], 
 [839529, "TOMATOS 1LB", 1.29, 25], 
 [483946, "MILK 1/2G", 3.45, 35], 
 [493402, "FLOUR 5LB", 2.99, 40], 
 [485034, "BELL PEPPERS 1LB", 1.35, 28], 
 [828391, "WHITE TUNA", 1.69, 100], 
 [449023, "CHEESE 1/2LB", 4.99, 15]
]
```

This is the list that I made into a dictionary. The output is supposed to look like this:

```
{
 847502: ['APPLES 1LB', 1.99, 50], 
 847283: ['OLIVE OIL', 10.99, 100], 
 839529: ['TOMATOS 1LB', 1.29, 25], 
 483946: ['MILK 1/2G', 3.45, 35], 
 493402: ['FLOUR 5LB', 2.99, 40], 
 485034: ['BELL PEPPERS 1LB', 1.35, 28], 
 828391: ['WHITE TUNA', 1.69, 100], 
 449023: ['CHEESE 1/2LB', 4.99, 15]
}
```

My code:

````
data = [["Suresh Datta", 57394, "suresh@example.com"], ["Colette Browning", 48539, "colette@example.com"], ["Skye Homsi", 58302, "skye@example.com"], ["Hiroto Yamaguchi", 48502, "hiroto@example.com"], ["Tobias Ledford", 48291, "tobias@example.com", "Tamara Babic", 58201, "tamara@example.com"], ["Jin Xu", 48293, "jin@example.com"], ["Joana Dias", 23945, "joana@example.com"], ["Alton Derosa", 85823, "alton@example.com"]] ```
inventory = {}
for e in data:
    inventory[e[0]] = e[1:4]
print(inventory)
````

The output I got in one notebook (please note this one is the correct output):

```
{
 847502: ['APPLES 1LB', 1.99, 50], 
 847283: ['OLIVE OIL', 10.99, 100],
 839529: ['TOMATOS 1LB', 1.29, 25],
 483946: ['MILK 1/2G', 3.45, 35],
 493402: ['FLOUR 5LB', 2.99, 40],
 485034: ['BELL PEPPERS 1LB', 1.35, 28],
 828391: ['WHITE TUNA', 1.69, 100],
 449023: ['CHEESE 1/2LB', 4.99, 15]}
```

The output I got when I put it in the notebook I was supposed to have it on

```
{
 847283: ['OLIVE OIL', 10.99, 100],
 485034: ['BELL PEPPERS 1LB', 1.35, 28],
 839529: ['TOMATOS 1LB', 1.29, 25],
 483946: ['MILK 1/2G', 3.45, 35],
 828391: ['WHITE TUNA', 1.69, 100],
 493402: ['FLOUR 5LB', 2.99, 40],
 847502: ['APPLES 1LB', 1.99, 50],
 449023: ['CHEESE 1/2LB', 4.99, 15]
}
```

Comment: The other notebook probably isn't using python 3.6+

Comment: Thanks i fixed the problem by changing the kernel to 3.6